# Bluetooth profiles for tablets

Tags: android, bluetooth, tablet

I want to know what profile will be better for implementing communication between device and tablet. The tablet will run on android platform? SPP or HID?
Which tablets are available to test the functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the applications for which you plan to use bluetooth... 
Wireless controllers, keyboard , mice etc HID will be the right way to go.
SPP is also useful to have as a general purpose profile to allow applications to be developed which can talk over bluetooth to other devices which support SPP

Comment: Thanks Dennis for your reply. But I think there are few devices with SPP support. Not all support this. So I want to make sure that the app works on most of the devices.